# Google cast - cast audio from my app with spotify api

Tags: google-cast-sdk

I'm currently building a school project where I implement Google cast.

I can cast video content. But I've also implemented Spotify API and I can play songs on my phone but I can't cast the audio.

```java
MediaInfo mediaInfo1 = new MediaInfo.Builder("https://open.spotify.com/track/7FojZdbGhhmg9x01VLwrJt?si=2039a3644cb04907")
    .setContentType("audio/basic")
    .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE).build();
remoteMediaClient.load(mediaInfo1);
```